# is <Function> similar as (req,res)

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am new to nodejs. referring to [this link](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener) section `http.createServer([options][, requestListener])`
i know how to create the `options` object. but for the `[, requestListener]`, it is stated in the docs that it is a `<Function>`. when i clicked on the link of `<Function>` which is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)
it indicates that that `<Function>` is a normal function that could be `lambda`, however, in the docs of `http.createServer([options][, requestListener])` as stated in the first link, it demonstrate the following:

```
http.createServer((req, res)
```

as far as i understood, the `(req, res)` is two different callbacks not a normal `<Function>`
to some extent. i am slightly befuddled.

1.would you please show me the difference between `(req,res)` and `<Function>`

2.where in docs `(req,res)` are explained. i want to know how can i configure or access properties of either of `req` and `res`

Comment: Those aren't callbacks, they're the arguments to the function that you're defining.

Comment: It should look like `http.createServer((req, res) => { your server code })`. That's an arrow function that takes 2 arguments.

Comment: @Barmar in which part of the docs it is explained please?how did you know that please?

Comment: @Barmar where can i find more details about these two arguments `req` and `res`

Comment: I suggest you look for a tutorial rather than trying to understand this from the reference documentation. That assumes you're familiar with general concepts of callback functions.

Comment: @Barmar do you mean that there is no info about `req` and `res` in the official docs of nodejs?i would like to see more info about these two arguments please

Comment: I'm sure it's in there somewhere, I just don't know exactly where.

Comment: The difference between `<Function>` and `(req, res) => {code}` is like the difference between `<Number>` and `3`. The first is a datatype, the second is a specific instance of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading the code. `(req, res)` is not a parameter to `createServer`. This entire thing is an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), a way to define an anonymous function:

```
(req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  res.end(JSON.stringify({
    data: 'Hello World!',
  }));
}
```

It is largely (but not completely) equivalent to:

```
function serverHandler(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  res.end(JSON.stringify({
    data: 'Hello World!',
  }));
}
```

The differences (not really important here, but for completeness' sake) are: the latter can be a function expression or a function statement, while the former is always an expression; the former does not redefine `this` while the latter does; and the former is not assigned to a variable, while the latter may be (`serverHandler` in this case).

Given the latter definition of `serverHandler`, you could use it as follows:

```
http.createServer(serverHandler)
```

An anonymous arrow function expression is just doing the same job as a function identifier in this latter example.

---

**EDIT** on where to find more documentation on `req` and `res`:

Per documentation of `createServer`:

> The `requestListener` is a function which is automatically added to the `'request'` event.

Per documentation of [`'request'` event](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/http.html#event-request), the event callback gets two parameters: `request`, an instance of [`IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage), and `response`, an instance of [`ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/http.html#class-httpserverresponse).

Comment: thank you. ii would like to know where can i find more info about `req` and `res` please?can you please show me where in the official docs they are explained please

Comment: I thought he wanted to know where it documents what `req` and `res` are in the function, although I think he's confused on multiple levels.

Comment: Added the relevant doc links.

Answer (score 2):

The `req` and `res` arguments to the callback are the same as the `request` and `response` properties of the corresponding [`request`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/http.html#event-request) event.

> **Event: 'request'**
> Added in: v0.1.0
>
> - `request` [`<http.IncomingMessage>`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage)
> - `response` [`<http.ServerResponse>`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/http.html#class-httpserverresponse)

You can then follow the links to the documentation of those datatypes to see how you use them in your server.

Comment: execuse me please, i found this as well https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/http.html    it includes details about `request` and `response`, is it also correct please?

Comment: Yes, those are the properties and methods of these objects.

Comment: so,which is more correct please, the two links you posted in your answer or the link i sent you in my last comment please?

Comment: I think they're the same thing